# Sorting ls output by file size

Tags: bash, sorting, ls

I am currently sorting the output of `ls -l` by byte count using:

```
ls -l | sort -r -k5,5 -n
```

What if I wanted to make this work with the `-@` flag? Currently this will output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 name  staff  7106  2 May 10:43 c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   675 22 Apr 17:57 a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   486 23 Apr 07:56 b
drwxr-xr-x  4 name  staff   136 25 Apr 18:38 d
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   120 23 Apr 07:59 e
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   112 22 Apr 18:45 g
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff    51 22 Apr 18:45 f
total 56
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
```

Where I want it to take the extended attribute keys line and keep it below the appropriate file like so:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 name  staff  7106  2 May 10:43 c
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   675 22 Apr 17:57 a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   486 23 Apr 07:56 b
drwxr-xr-x  4 name  staff   136 25 Apr 18:38 d
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   120 23 Apr 07:59 e
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff   112 22 Apr 18:45 g
-rwxr-xr-x  1 name  staff    51 22 Apr 18:45 f
total 56
```

Comment: It would be really useful (and maybe even necessary) to post your file being sorted before any sorting is done, so that we can understand what is really needed to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `sort`, just use the `-S` option with `ls`

```
ls -Sl
```

(that's an upper case S)